# Beta and production app using same core data ios

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, app-store, beta

I have users using the my ios app which is downloaded from app store which has business critical data. i wanted new version to be tested by them before releasing them so i changed my bundle identifier and my app name and installed application through XCode directly (App store build connected to Production server and direct build connected to QA) but when opening the beta app it uses the data already present in the production app (i.e phone number and other details are same as production app to this i think it is using same core data files). i tried changing my NSPersistentContainer name in app Delegate i even changed my xcmodelname but still the same result.
I am storing the user data so i can log him in once registration process is complete. but the beta app is picking up that data and directly logging in

Should i change some thing else  for it to use different core data files

Thanks 
Sorry if the question seems vague tried the best i can explain

Comment: Check that if both Production and QA server having same data?

Comment: No they have different data I have added a feature if user data is present I log him in directly here it is taking the same user data from production app and trying to log him in to the qa server.

Comment: There has to be more to this, because the changes you have made are more than enough on their own. There are no extra steps; you've done what's needed and more, so there must be more to the story.

Comment: that is all actually any suggestions please help i need to deliver this asap thanks

Comment: let modelURL = bundle.url(forResource: "", withExtension:"momd")! was still using previous database name thanks